# Removing Quote inside <title> tag

Tags: html, .net, seo, title

[image: Note the quote that is wrapping around this tag]

The code I used to Produce This is the same as the one WITHOUT this problem

(just pulling from a different database column)

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childspec.titlew)) {
                    wtitle = childspec.titlew;
                    ltlMasterPageTitle.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(wtitle) + "";
                    } else {
                    wtitle = childspec.laytitle;
                    ltlMasterPageTitle.Text = "Company Name - " + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(wtitle);
                    }
```

here is the code that does the output.
When its the ELSE case then the content does not have a wrapper around this

not sure if this is a serious SEO issue as well**

ALSO how do i **remove** this **extra Tab** space infront of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know where the extra space came from but I just applied

```
Trim()
```

again before the output code and it removed all extra spacing and quotes